# Binding a table column containing NSPopUpButtons

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings

I've got a table one column of which uses an NSPopUpButtonCell. Try as I might, I can't seem to figure out the way to properly bind everything the way I want it. Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have an NSArrayController plucking items from a managed object context, called 'Field Values'. This is to be used to populate the popup menu for each item (i.e. the list of available choices). I can bind this by selecting the cell in IB and binding its content/objects/values to 'Field Values'.arrangedObjects and 'Field Values'.arrangedObjects.name as appropriate (to get the represented object and the visible title).

I then want to bind the column in such a way that the selected value in each row comes from an array in my controller class, again made visible (and only edited through) another NSArrayController.

So far I've managed to set it up so that every popup menu contains the list of available fields, and that the default value is selected in each of them. Actually selecting an item has no effect, however— it just snaps back to its initial value. I've also managed to find some other variations on this, such as the menu being populated with the selected values, or containing the name of all available values, and the selection containing the `-description` of the 'none' value I added.

I'm sure I'm missing something fairly simple, but I'm not sure what it is. Presumably there's some subtlety I've missed in how to bind this sort of data (i.e. the Content vs. Content Object vs. Content Value things), but I'm damned if I can see it right now.

Many thanks in advance :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a similar set up with a table view, although the data source isn't Core Data based, but I saw one thing you might double check that could be a subtle difference.  In my setup for the table column, I have the table column itself bound via content, contentValues, and selectedObject. However, it looks like it's also possible to do the bindings on the actual NSPopUpButtonCell instead.  Perhaps it works when the bindings are on the table column, but not when they're on the actual cell?  Anyway, there's one thing that might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

Never bind to scroll view, table view or cell.
However, ever bind to table columns.

Watch the title of the Inspector window to be certain of what you're binding.